# Ionic template content not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, state, ionic-framework

I've made a basic menu navigation with Ionic using **ion-side-menus** and an Angular state mechanism as described at http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/ but no content is showing up in the center section of the page when home is loaded or any of the menu's items are clicked. Here's the simplified HTML ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-side-menus>

        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-header">
                <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
                <button class="button button-icon">
                    <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
                </button>
            </ion-header-bar>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

        <!-- Left menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="item in menuItems" item="item" ng-click="enterState(item.id)">
                    <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.name}}
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>

    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Home">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>HOME</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="page2.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Page 2">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>PAGE 2</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="page3.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Page 3">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>PAGE 3</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the controller JS ...

```
angular.module('testapp', ['ionic'])
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        "use strict";

        /* Set up the states for the application's different sections. */
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {name: 'home', url: '/home', templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
            .state('page2', {name: 'page2', url: '/page2', templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
            .state('page3', {name: 'page3', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page3.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
        ;
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
        "use strict";

        /* Items for left side menu. */
        $scope.menuItems = [
            {id: 'page2', name: 'Page 2', icon: 'icon ion-person-stalker'},
            {id: 'page3', name: 'Page 3', icon: 'icon ion-person-stalker'}
        ];

        $scope.toggleSideMenu = function() {
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
        };

        $scope.enterState = function(stateID) {
            $state.transitionTo(stateID);
        };

        $scope.enterState('home');
        $scope.$state = $state;
    })
```

The correct URL shows up so I suppose the state mechanism is working properly but the Ionic content in the Angular templates isn't appearing. Can anyone more experienced with Ionic give me a hint what is wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### SHORT ANSWER

You have at least two issues:

- in controller you call `$scope.enterState('home');`. On other hand each state calls the same controller. Therefore you enter to the same state `home`.

  Remove this line and add in `config`: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');`
- In HTML add  `<ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>`

That's all.

Here is working <kbd>**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ilsHA)**</kbd>

### WORKING CODE

---

*HTML*

```
<html ng-app="testapp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Login</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-side-menus>

        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-header">
                <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 class="title">Home1</h1>
                <button class="button button-icon">
                    <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
                </button>
            </ion-header-bar>
        
         
        <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
      
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      
      

        <!-- Left menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="item in menuItems" item="item" ng-click="enterState(item.id)">
                    <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.name}}
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>

    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Home">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>HOME</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="page2.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Page 2">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>PAGE 2</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="page3.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view title="Page 3">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <p>PAGE 3</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

*JS*

```
angular.module('testapp', ['ionic'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        "use strict";

        /* Set up the states for the application's different sections. */
        $stateProvider           
            .state('home', {name: 'home', url: '/home', templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
            .state('page2', {name: 'page2', url: '/page2', templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
            .state('page3', {name: 'page3', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page3.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
        ;
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
        "use strict";
      

        /* Items for left side menu. */
        $scope.menuItems = [
            {id: 'page2', name: 'Page 2', icon: 'icon ion-person-stalker'},
            {id: 'page3', name: 'Page 3', icon: 'icon ion-person-stalker'}
        ];

        $scope.toggleSideMenu = function() {
          
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
        };

        $scope.enterState = function(stateID) {
          console.log(stateID);
            $state.transitionTo(stateID);
        };

       //$scope.enterState('home');
      
        $scope.$state = $state;
    })
```

Comment: For some reason my view content does not show when I use the <script> method. The controller does indeed load though. What could be the reason please? Thanks!