# Go to a specific page in ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Im stuck in a problem that i have to open a specific page in ionic framework using the controller.
I have to go to the following page

```
#/tab/hotel_details/1
```

when i click ok button in the ionic popup window

```
 $scope.showAlert = function() {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Click OK for further details',
   });
   alertPopup.then(function(res) {
   //Go to a specific page
   });
 };
```

I cant use `$state.go("tab.hotel_details");` , because i have to go to `hotel_details/1` 
I have to get rid of the above problem for further development of my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ionic template content not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242075/ionic-template-content-not-showing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the id in the second parameter of the call to `$state.go` :

```
$state.go("tab.hotel_details", { "id": id })
```

Then, in your controller, you can retrieve the value from `$stateParams` :

```
var id = Number($stateParams.id)
```

Reference: [Angular-ui State](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1)

Answer (score -1):

You can still use the $location service if you want to navigate to a particular url instead of navigating by a state.

```
$location.path('/tab/hotel_details/1');
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me, the accepted answer did work though.